# Slow client-side autocomplete w/jQuery

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

My page has a scatter plot of data values for a list of genes.  The list can be 30,000+.  I have all the data on the client, so my autocomplete is as follows:

html:

```
<label>Search for a specific gene:</label> <input size=25 maxlength=100 id=gene_autocomplete class="autocomplete" />
```

css:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-width: 275px;
            max-height: 300px; 
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            padding-right: 20px;
```

}

```
ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-right: 15px;
```

}

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

...

$("input#gene_autocomplete").autocomplete({source: data.ids, minLength:4});

... followed by parsing a data file
```

---

```
parseGct: function(dataText) {

    var rows = dataText.split('\n');

    this.vals = new Array();
    this.colNames = rows[2].split('\t').splice(2);
    for(var i = 3; i < rows.length; i++) {

        var cols = rows[i].split('\t');
        if(cols.length < 2) continue;
                    var data = cols.slice(2);
        this.toFloat(data);
        this.vals.push(data.slice());
    }
},
```

I have experimented with different delays (0 to 700), to no avail.  Generally the browser times out.  What can I do to speed this up?

Comment: I need some clarification. When someone types in a few letters, jQuery has to search through 30,000 records to retrieve a shortened list for display? Or is the problem more related to the initialization or initial display of the autocomplete?

Comment: Some a more extensive example/sample code of you jQuery approach and webpage would be extremely useful in helping you find a solution to your problem

Comment: I'm not sure but think it's the latter.  The browser usually complains before any results pop up in the autocomplete field.

Comment: Are you sure the autocomplete widget is to blame? How are your 30,000+ ids generated? The browser might very well be stuck doing that.

Comment: It seems to me that parsing 30,000 text elements out of a tabbed file in JavaScript might just be a very slow operation. Instead of parsing it, you could try storing it in a way that the browser might handle natively, like JSON or XML. You might also store that information in a database and query it server side and use a caching mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, everyone (this was my first post).  I'm going to try the JSON method.